# nested asp.net Repeater using entity data model 4.5

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I'm trying to make nested repeater using Entity Data Model 4.5, but result is not as expected.
I searched for a solution but I didn't find any good answer. Most of these topics are talking about how to make it using DataSet.

asp.net:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptChannels" runat="server" DataSourceID="edsChannels">
<ItemTemplate>
    <div class="channel">
        <span><%# Eval("ChannelName")%></span>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptChannelsPosts" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("ChannelsPosts")%>'>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="channelPost">
                    <span><%# Eval("Title")%></span>
                    <span><%# Eval("Description")%></span>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

no cs code.

About the .edmx file, it contains 2 entities (Channels, ChannelsPosts), and there's a relation between them.

Result:
Only channels names are displayed on page and no ChannelsPosts is displayed.

```
Channel 1
Channel 2
Channel 3
```

I don't know exactly where's the wrong part of my code, please help.

```
Channel 1
     Post 1.1
     Post 1.2
Channel 2
     Post 2.1
Channel 3
     Post 3.1
     Post 3.2
     Post 3.3
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use EntityDatasource with nested repeaters, you will need two EntityDatasource and they should be structured like:

```
<Outer Repeater>
    <Inner Repeater>
    </Inner Repeater>
    <Inner EntityDatasource />
</Outer Repeater>
<Outer EntityDatasource />
```

You will need to pass the Channel ID from outer repeater to inner EntityDatasource. Add a hidden field inside the outer repeater to hold the ChannelID. In the inner EntityDatasource add a control parameter with ControlId to the hidden field. Your markup should look like below:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptChannels" runat="server" DataSourceID="edsChannels">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="channel">
            <span><%# Eval("ChannelName")%></span>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnId" Value='<%#Eval("Id") %>' runat="server" />
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptChannelsPosts" runat="server" DataSourceID="edsChannelsPosts">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="channelPost">
                        <span><%# Eval("Title")%></span>
                        <span><%# Eval("Description")%></span>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
            <asp:EntityDataSource ID="edsChannelsPosts" 
                runat="server" ConnectionString="name=EDMTestEntities" 
                DefaultContainerName="EDMTestEntities" CommandText="" 
                EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="ChannelsPosts" 
                EntityTypeFilter="ChannelsPost" Where="it.channel=@channel">
                    <WhereParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hdnId" PropertyName="Value" Type="int32" DefaultValue="" Name="channel"/>           
                </WhereParameters>
            </asp:EntityDataSource>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="edsChannels" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="name=EDMTestEntities" 
    DefaultContainerName="EDMTestEntities" 
    EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="Channels">
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

And output should be like this:

[image]

[Here's](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6i8p65gmkp0NGhkTU5HdFFlNmM/edit?usp=sharing) a link to my test project.

Comment: Thank you so much, your test project is so helpful, :).